# Bootstrap's Modal is not working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

Im trying to test the sample modals for my project but even the codes from jfiddles is not working on me. When i clicked the button, it only gives me a dimmed window. I also tried to google this but gives me nothing

**This is the modal code im trying.**

```
<body>
<p>Link 1</p>
    <a data-toggle="modal" data-id="ISBN564541" title="Add this item" class="open-AddBookDialog btn btn-primary" href="#addBookDialog">test</a>

    <p>&nbsp;</p>


    <p>Link 2</p>
    <a data-toggle="modal" data-id="ISBN-001122" title="Add this item" class="open-AddBookDialog btn btn-primary" href="#addBookDialog">test</a>

    <div class="modal hide" id="addBookDialog">
     <div class="modal-header">
        <button class="close" data-dismiss="modal">×</button>
        <h3>Modal header</h3>
      </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <p>some content</p>
            <input type="text" name="bookId" id="bookId" value=""/>
        </div>
    </div>

       <script src="js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
           <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
          <script src="js/ckeditor.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).on("click", ".open-AddBookDialog", function () {
         var myBookId = $(this).data('id');
         $(".modal-body #bookId").val( myBookId );
    });
</script>
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/2bRbk/)

You are missing the `data-target` to display.

```
<a data-target="#myModal" data-toggle="modal" data-id="ISBN564541" title="Add this item" class="open-AddBookDialog btn btn-primary" href="#addBookDialog" data-toggle="modal">test</a>

<div id="myModal" role="dialog">
     ....
</div>
```

Comment: I got it now. Thanks dude.

Answer (score 1):

Taken from [Bootstrap's demo](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals)

```
<button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
  Launch demo modal
</button>
```

The modal is targeted via the `data-target` attribute and not `href` like you have here.

Comment: I got it now. Thank you!